# Show total line count status bar sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a code to put in the settings or a plugin that will show the total number of lines along the current line and column in the status bar in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: If you're looking for plugins, please use Package Control's [search function](https://packagecontrol.io/search). Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have already looked at plugins but I was thinking some code in the user profile might do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code to show the number of lines in the status bar is very simple,
just get the number of lines

```py
line_count = view.rowcol(view.size())[0] + 1
```

and write the to the status bar

```py
view.set_status("line_count", "#Lines: {0}".format(line_count))
```

If you want to pack in a plugin you just need to write this in a function and call it on some [EventListener](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener).
Create a plugin by clicking `Tools >> Developer >> New Plugin...` and paste:

```py
import time
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

last_change = time.time()
update_interval = 1.5  # s


class LineCountUpdateListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def update_line_count(self, view):
        line_count = view.rowcol(view.size())[0] + 1
        view.set_status("line_count", "#Lines: {0}".format(line_count))

    def on_modified(self, view):
        global last_change
        current_change = time.time()
        # check if we haven't embedded the change in the last update
        if current_change > last_change + update_interval:
            last_change = current_change
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.update_line_count(view),
                                int(update_interval * 1000))

    on_new = update_line_count
    on_load = update_line_count
```

This does in essentially call the command, when creating a new view, loading a file, and modifying the views content. For performance reason it has some logic to not call it on every modification.

Comment: One small issue with this is that it does not trigger on currently opened tabs at the moment that it is installed for the first time. It might seem small, but this caused me a lot of confusion and I wasted some time debugging this because I couldn't figure out why the plugin did not work at first.

Answer (score 1):

Goto menu -> find -> find in files.

Then select regex.

use this pattern to count line including white spaces in each line-

```
^(.*)$
```

To count the number of lines excluding white spaces, use pattern

```
^.*\S+.*$
```

you can specify if you exclude some directories of file types like

```
c:\your_project_folder\,*.php,*.phtml,*.js,*.inc,*.html, -*/folder_to_exclude/*
```

Note - Characters other than white spaces will get also count because they too have start and end with white space.